# How to properly reference an answer that is on the same question's page

Tags: support, feature-request, answers, hyperlinks

When I want to reference a previous answer on the same question's page, I normally click the answer's *share* link and copy the entire URL and use it in my comment or answer.

However, when this link is clicked, the page is reloaded...

This URL is different from the question's URL and currently, by *inspecting*, we know that each answer has an `id="answer-ANSWER_ID"`. Therefore if we use the `#` reference in this way:

> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/**QUESTION-ID**/**QUESTION-TITLE**#answer-**ANSWER_id**

The browser just scrolls to that ID (without reloading). Is this OK to do? Or will these IDs change in the future?... Or is it simply bad in terms of [SEO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Search_engine_optimization) (if the question's title is changed, or due to other reasons)?

P.S.: Related to these, using comments `id`s is acceptable as well?

P.P.S: It'd be useful to reference titles in really long answers, i.e., if each `<h2>` would have an auto-assigned id, we would be able to do so...

Comment: You can use the _share_ button below the answer.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ yes, that's what I have been doing... My question is, is it ok to use the answer's `id` in the question's URL?

Comment: And for comments, the timestamp is a link (which shouldn't refresh the page)

Comment: @TZHX yes, I also inspected that (that's why I mentioned comment's `id`s), so I assume these won't be changed in the future, right?

Comment: I wouldn't assume anything with regards to comments -- they can be (and often are) deleted fairly easily. If you feel the need to reference them, you should probably be quoting the relevant parts (with appropriate attribution). And relying on anything other than the "approved" means of sharing links to posts (the 'share' link format) could lead to changes in the way SO manages their HTML rendering breaking your links.

Comment: @TZHX in old answer's, [old upvoted comments like this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11227809/why-is-processing-a-sorted-array-faster-than-an-unsorted-array#comment14752910_11227902) are very unlikely to be deleted, and they often complement well the answer's information...

Comment: [The browser clearly reloads](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/297485#answer-297526)

Comment: @TravisJ Unless you use an `id` in the URL's link (e.g. `#answer-ANSWER_id`). By your comment, I am not sure if you were trying to know that... However, in the comments of the answer below (which you linked), someone previously mentioned that these `id` URLs may not work in questions where there is pagination due to the large amount of answers. So it's better to avoid using them.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The problem with just using the question id in the URL, with the answer id in the hash, is that it won't work properly if there are multiple pages of answers.  Admittedly, this doesn't happen often (mostly on popular meta posts). The question title is irrelevant, the URL will work if you put gibberish there or remove it entirely.

The canonical way to link to a post is to use the link you get when you click "share" beneath the post. Given that multiple pages of answers is unlikely on a normal question, adding the hash instead is probably ok, but it is not required.

Comment: There's another reason it won't always work properly: Think merged questions.

Comment: @Deduplicator I think the old question id redirects to the merge target, and the answer id would stay the same.  But I'm not sure, I don't have an example.

Comment: +1 I honestly didn't remember the pagination problem, where `#id` may not work at all. Changing the page seems not to be done through an AJAX call, so a page reload happens. I guess I may keep using the _share_ link after all. Thanks David.

Answer (score 4):

> Although this question [already has been answered](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/45597/how-can-i-link-to-a-specific-answer), it cannot be
> flagged as a duplicate since its in a different community. So i'm
> summarizing the answers from that community below for anyone who finds themselves here.

You can choose from either of the below 2 options:

1. [**Simplest way**](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/45598/381523): Using the share button at the bottom of every answer

[image: Image showing the "Share link to an answer" feature in Stack Overflow]

2. [**Recursive method**](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/45600/381523): Recursive method - this is ideal since this doesn't trigger a page reload (after 1st click)

   - Copy and store the URL of the question in a notepad (example:
     `https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/297485/how-to-properly-reference-an-answer-that-is-in-the-same-questions-page`)
   - Then click on the "share" button on the specific answer you would
     like to link to and copy the URL (example: `https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/297526/6908282`)
   - Append the first numeric value from step2 to the URL in step1 like below `https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/297485/how-to-properly-reference-an-answer-that-is-in-the-same-questions-page/297526#297526`

     Note: You need to add the number **twice** (with a # in between) so that the page doesn't reload if you click multiple times.

---

### Update:

The only caveat with the "Recursive method" mentioned above is that it removes your `userid` which is used by Stack Overflow to track the posts you share and for awarding [publicist badge](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/262/publicist) accordingly